# How to pass a value back from Java controller to Thymeleaf front-end?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, thymeleaf

I am building an application that when the user selects a value from a `select` tag, then the user is prompted with another `select` tag with corresponding data. I achieve this by grabbing the data from the first field and using Ajax to pass it back to my controller and then compute it and send back new data. However, I am having difficulty sending the object back. I am not sure if I am doing it right. I tried using `model.addAttribute()` but I believe I set it up wrong.

**Tools:**

```
Java 
Spring Boot
Thymeleaf
Bootstrap
```

**Controller:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/ajax/searchUserProfiles.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public  @ResponseBody void getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestBody TestApp mTestApp, HttpServletRequest request) {
            String val = mTestApp.getDtoTiername();
            List<String> t1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(TestApp temp: exampleAry) {

                if(temp.getDtoTiername().equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
                    t1.add(temp.getDtoSystem());
                }
            }

            //I want to return t1 to my select tag in my front-end

        }
```

**Ajax:**

```
  function searchText() {
       var search = {
          "dtoTiername" : "Web"  
       }

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType : 'json',
           url: "/ajax/searchUserProfiles.html",
           data: JSON.stringify(search), // Note it is important
           success :function(result) {
           // do what ever you want with data
           }
       });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col col-lg-9 search-bar">
              <div class="form-group">                 
                  <label>Tier:</label>                           
             <select class="js-example-basic-single" th:field="*{ary4}" id="selectData1">
                         <option value=""></option>
                         <option th:each="ary4 : ${ary4}"
                            th:value="${ary4.dtoTiername}"
                            th:text="${ary4.dtoTiername}"/>
                  </select>
                    <div class="text-right">

                </div> 
              </div> 
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-9 search-bar">
                <div class="form-group">                 
                    <label>Type:</label>              
                   <select class="js-example-basic-single" th:field="*{t1}" id="selectData2">
                         <option value=""></option>
                         <option th:each="t1 : ${t1}"
                            th:value="${t1.dtoTiername}"
                            th:text="${t1.dtoTiername}"/>
                  </select>

                      <div class="text-right">

                  </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What is ary6, does that even compile? Also a search method should be GET, not POST, hence you would need to pass the "search" data in the url, not the request body. You want to return stuff and it's an ajax petition, not an html reload, so your responsebody annotation is OK, but your method should return whatever you need and not void. You probably dont need to add .html to the mapping if you are using the default config, and you don't need the request parameter if you are not gonna do something fancy. Once you do all this, there are many posts in SO about filling a select via ajax.

Comment: @Jorge.V So I made an edit to display my HTML code that I am using. The ```ary6``` was just an example array I am using. So I listened to want you said however, even when I change the @ResponseBody to pass the value I want back, it does not update the thymeleaf ```t1``` in front-end. I tried setting the adding a parameter in the method ```Model model```  and then pass a ```model.addAttribute()``` but that too did not help. I am lost in my next steps.

Answer (score 1):

So far dropdown is concerned, it contains both option value and option text. But if you want to use both values same that can also be done. For it,

modify your controller code as

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajax/searchUserProfiles.html",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody List<String> getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestBody String mTestApp, HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<String> t1 = new ArrayList<>();
        t1.add("AAAA"); // i added sample text, however you can fetch values from dao as well
        t1.add("BBBBB");
        return t1;
    }
```

Update your javascript code as

```
 function searchText() {
       var search = {
          "dtoTiername" : "Web"
       }
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType : 'json',
           url: "/ajax/searchUserProfiles.html",
           data: JSON.stringify(search),
           success :function(result) {
            $.each(result,function(i,obj)
                {
                 var div_data="<option value="+obj+">"+obj+"</option>"; //this would modify if you return map from java instead of list
                $(div_data).appendTo('#testing'); //append new dynamically generated option to element having id "testing"
                });
           }
       });
  }
```

Please ensure that your have html select option with id specified in above script as below

```
<select id="testing"></select>
```

With above code, if you call js function searchText multiple times, multiple copies of option will be appended to the drop-down. Now it will be your use case to empty\append\block in such scenario.

Also the controller code should go in class annotated with `@RestController`, not in `@Controller` class which returns `ModelAndView`

EDIT : use html page as

```
    <html>
    <script>
   // Here paste script provided
    </script>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="searchText()" />
     <select id="testing"></select>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: So this somewhat helped me, but my goal is to have the user choose a value from the first ```select``` tag. Then, pass that value back and do a computation, then pass a corresponding values to another ```select``` tag. The code you provided looks like it just creates different select tags. I just want to update the select with the values without reloading the page.

Comment: Also, I added my HTML code to the post. So if you can, please take a look.

Comment: Is this HTML page served by thymeleaf ? Does both the dropdown already have data when  page loads for first time ? Is ajax function called on click of first "forward" button ? I apologise to ask so many questions to understand the thing

Comment: No worries, so first off I meant to take the buttons down, they don't do anything anymore. Second, yes the HTML page is served by thymeleaf ```ModelAndView```. Third, no the dropdown does not have data already in it. Also thanks again for at least responding to my question. I appreciate it

Comment: Alright, make a new controller class annotated with @RestController. Use my controller method in it. Have an html as I am providing, add function i provided in script and try to execute it. Serve this page html page instead of yours.

Comment: So I did it and it works, though I feel this is just a long and not the proper way of coding it. Also, if I do use it, that means I would have to remove the appended content once I choose a different value in the first selection? Correct?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to do it through thymeleaf.

Comment: Nevermind, I used your code and got it working. Thanks

Comment: Yes you will have to remove appended content once choose a different value in the first selection. There are 2 approaches and it completely depends on use case. Either you can have both dropdown prepopulated when page is served and then use jquery to filter record in second dropdown based on selection of first. OR serve first dropwdown from thymeleaf and use ajax to fetch data for next. Anyhow js has to be used and there is no complete thymeleaf solution.